# Combine multiple internet sources from same city in one

Tags: networking

I have at work a 8MBps, at my parents a 8MBps and lets say at home a 4MBps internet connection. They all are in the same city and the ping and transfer between them is VERY GOOD. (not the same house/location... they are 10-15km apart..). like I said I can transfer files between them at top speeds because its some sort of local network...

How can I get at home 20MBps ? Or at least a round robin / least used like download of stuff choosing a diffrent source everytime

I have unrestricted access to all routers.

Comment: You can download individual parts of large file collections at each location and then drive between them all collecting them on a USB stick. You cannot simply add the speed of one connection to some other arbitrary connection without having a third (faster) connection between the two places.

Comment: How can I get at home 20 MBps?" You cannot.  What you describe is not realistic nor is it possible.

Comment: Could you give us more details about the connections? Is it some kind of municipal network where local (city-wide or country-wide if small country) access is uncapped but Internet access is throttled? What technology does it use (DSL, Fiber, ...)?

Comment: "I have unrestricted access to all routers."   **No, you don't**  Your ISP has routers on their premises that you don't control.  Also tell us what speed you consider "top speed" in mbps.

Comment: @Mokubai like I said, I HAVE the 3rd connection between them. It's the city network that is 100MBps.  I don't want to download individual parts, I want round robin. For example: I download a torrent, I choose the 1st connection to do it. I watch youtube, I choose the 2nd..etc. with all streaming to my computer... which acts like a server.

Comment: Possibly loosely related: [Merging two incoming broadband lines for faster Internet](https://superuser.com/q/660798/354511), [Is it possible to combine two internet connections to increase performance?](https://superuser.com/q/239546/354511), [Can I combine two LANs into one to get double speed?](https://superuser.com/q/240122/354511), and [Two WANs to one LAN; what router do I need?](https://superuser.com/q/275573/354511)

Comment: @Mokubai: This question is painfully unclear, but I’m guessing that the OP has 100mbps between their home, their work, and their parents’ home, but only slow (4 to 8mbps) between the sites in the city and the rest of the world (e.g., Stack Exchange, Amazon.com, YouTube, etc.). It seems to me that something like what they want ought to be possible; see the questions I linked to.

Comment: @G-Man fair enough. I'm sure that wasnt in the question before,  but no worries. Hopefully he gets an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation it would seem that you would indeed be able to combine* multiple Internet access.

A possible way of doing this would be:

1. create a VPN access (server) at work and parent
2. configure VPN client for both work and parent at home
3. configure the home router to use its default gateway, VPN1 and VPN2 as load-balanced WANs

While possible, the configuration would probably be quite involved, but would definitely be a fun experiment in networking :)

Note: each connection would be limited to the speed of the internet connection it is using, but the total would be (approximately) the sum of the different speeds. You could reach full speed for a single connection by using an external server that "recombines" your different connections, at the cost of complexity and latency.